# in which format this code is encoded ? and how i decode it?

Tags: encryption, passwords

"jmHMRWncShQ%3D" this is my encoded text , i want to know that in which format , this text was encoded , and also want to know that how i decode these types of code ??? this password may be encryptetion . .

Answer (score 3):

as @0xhughes says there's a lot of instinct to working these things out however a couple of basic points about your sample

- the %3D at the end makes it very like that it's URL encoded as that's a URL encoding of the = character
- After that the = character at the end makes it very likely it's base64 encoded as that's the padding character for a base64 encoded string and is commonly seen at the end of it.

Comment: sir can u suggest me any software or web site to decode this type of code ???

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you just have to use your gut and experience to determine what your looking at. If it's a password, generally some type of hashing, salting and or encoding has been applied, and the output can vary greatly. Check this website out and see if anything you generate looks similar to your output there. Might be a good place to START.

http://www.insidepro.com/hashes.php?lang=eng